# Sample ATL Dialog Window

Tags: c++, visual-studio, user-interface, atl

Can anyone help me find an up-to-date, working ATL project which has a main window and some components in it? Please, for the love of god, don't tell me to use WTL/Qt or others. I need ATL. There's no up-to-date project about it. I just need a main window, that's all. I can figure out the rest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try creating one using the default settings? This works usually when getting started.

Comment: Don't know why you're so afraid of WTL, it's meant to fill in the missing pieces of ATL. I think it's even by the same authors.

Comment: @MarkRansom: The OP should have linked his previous questions, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11171795/creating-uis-with-atl "I read that WTL is a better option for UI creation. However, people insisted on ATL."

Comment: This tiny program that I'm going to write - don't laugh - will be used in a thin client. It has low system resources and the previous applications all use ATL, so they insisted on ATL. I'm not familiar with these C statements. I get lost whenever I look at the source codes. There are 0 comments, no indentation, no readability whatsoever. So, I'm just staring at the source code crying and asking myself "What did I do wrong?". Things are really messed up. But, thanks to Roman R, I guess it'll start becoming smooth. Thank you very much. I'm a big fan of yours. You're the hero of atl tag. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, for the love of god: Visual Studio 2010 C++/ATL EXE project from template + dialog window.

Source:

- Trac: [AtlDialogSample](http://www.alax.info/trac/public/browser/trunk/Utilities/AtlDialogSample)
- SVN: [AtlDialogSample](http://www.alax.info/svn/public/trunk/Utilities/AtlDialogSample/)

This is of your primary interest:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CMainDialog

class CMainDialog :
    public CDialogImpl<CMainDialog>
{
public:
    enum { IDD = IDD_MAIN };

BEGIN_MSG_MAP(CMainDialog)
    MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_INITDIALOG, OnInitDialog)
    COMMAND_ID_HANDLER(IDCANCEL, OnCommand)
    COMMAND_ID_HANDLER(IDOK, OnCommand)
END_MSG_MAP()

public:
// CMainDialog

// Window Message Handlers
    LRESULT OnInitDialog(UINT nMessage, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, BOOL& bHandled)
    {
        ATLVERIFY(CenterWindow());
        return 0;
    }
    LRESULT OnCommand(UINT, INT nIdentifier, HWND, BOOL& bHandled)
    {
        ATLVERIFY(EndDialog(nIdentifier));
        return 0;
    }
};
```

and

```
VOID RunMessageLoop()
{
    CMainDialog Dialog;
    Dialog.DoModal();
}
```

[image]

Comment: I know you'll beat me to death, but I get these errors: `1>C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(113,5): error MSB3073: The command ""C:\Users\E\Desktop\rr\Debug\AtlDialogSample.exe" /RegServer
1>C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(113,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code -2147319780. `Thank you very much.

Comment: This project is fully featured COM server (because the template project gives you that, and I was to add minimal changes from there), and as such its `/regserver` run attempts to register with system registry. This requires elevated privileges to succeed. This however does not seem to be necessary for UI. All in all, make sure you build from Visual Studio started As Administrator. Or just ignore this error.

Comment: This project changes PreMessageLoop function. I guess it's not how it's supposed to work.

Comment: If you step inside `PreMessageLoop` function, you'd see it exits the application in caseof COM support without COM classes hosted. This lets code reach `RunMessageLoop`. So it is how it is supposed to work: you either have real COM server there, or you change this function.