# Unable to Create Exit Button

Tags: c++, visual-c++, user-interface, atl

I tried a tutorial about C and ATL about a basic dialog. It has a window, and 2 buttons inside. In the beginning of the tutorial, there are 2 buttons and they all exit the application. But, these 2 buttons are created by default. So, I tried creating another button that can exit the application, and I failed.

My aim is to use radio buttons with this project. I want to create some radio buttons and when I press a button, I want to execute some commands.

Here are the links - In my opinion, the tutorial link is unrelated, but I guess it won't hurt: [Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6893/Simple-ATL-dialog-based-exe), [Working Project](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/20637331/zort/DlgTest.zip), [Problematic Project](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/20637331/zort/hede.zip).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You add a button onto dialog resource template
2. You associate an identifier with the button in properties pane right there in resource editor, e.g. `IDC_MYBUTT`
3. You will find `#define` for the chosen constant `IDC_MYBUTT` in `resource.h` file on the project
4. You add handlers to button events on your dialog class. Those are `COMMAND_ID_HANDLER` macros on [Sample ATL Dialog Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194785/sample-atl-dialog-window) code, which connect the event (underlying `WM_COMMAND` message sent to the window) with specific method (both `IDOK` and `IDCANCEL` buttons execute `OnCommand` in the sample code).
5. There on the handler you decide how to handle, and in particular to end the dialog or not.

`COMMAND_HANDLER`, `COMMAND_ID_HANDLER` and friends are described on MSDN: [Message Map Macros (ATL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hk23896b.aspx).